# PHP equivilant to JQuery AJAX jsonp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make the following query on the server side, which means unless I want to install a server side JS framework, I need to do it in PHP. I've used CURL for POST before but it doesn't seem to work for this. This is the code I need to replicate:

```
         $.ajax({
            url: "https://stuff.com/stuff/stuff/?callback=?",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            data: 
            {
                a: A,
                b: B,
                c: C,
                d: D
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
            }  
        });
```

A, B, C, and D will all be passed to the PHP script as URL parameters. Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<?php
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'blah/?callback=?');
    curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);\

    $buffer = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    echo $buffer;
?>
```

This is what I have right now, but I have no clue how to add jsonp arguments. I believe they go in the URL, but I can't figure out how to format them.

Comment: Can you post what you've got for your attempt with CURL?  It would make a better starting point.

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: Look into `curl_setopt`'s `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` setting.

Comment: I don't think POST is what I need, I'm trying to send a jsonp request

Comment: @Nathan Probably not. `JSONP` is *generally* used when you can't do a `POST`. JavaScript has a cross-origin security policy JSONP is intended to workaround, but with PHP you can just make the call to the API as a `POST` without the `callback=`.

Comment: Tried enabling POST, it says the URI I'm trying to access can't be found... But if I comment out the line, it gives me a no arguments error.

Comment: @ceejayoz — No. JSONP is generally used when you can't do use XHR. GET vs POST is mostly orthogonal to that (although JSONP forces GET, you wouldn't generally use POST unless you were sending new data to the server instead of requesting data from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a query string with [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

This example uses a YQL endpoint to demonstrate (since, unsurprisingly, `blah/?callback=?` doesn't resolve for me). `q`, `format`, etc map on to `a`, `b`, etc in the question.

```
<?php

$url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$query = array(
    "q" => 'SELECT * FROM google.books WHERE q="barack obama" AND maxResults=1',
    "format" => "json",
    "env" => "store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys",
    "callback" => "callback_name",
);

$url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($query);

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$buffer = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
echo $buffer;

?>
```

You'll then need to strip off the padding from the response.

JSONP is a (fairly dirty) hack to get around the same origin policy in browsers. You don't need it when making a request without involving a browser, so if the endpoint you are requesting data from supports plain JSON, use that instead.

Comment: I'll try now! Is that full $query array the data I'm passing in? Or are some of those fields actually required for the request. Just trying to figure out how I'd insert my `data` field into this.

Comment: @Nathan — As I said at the top of the quest, that is your `data` field. (Although you'll need to add `callback` to it if you're requesting JSONP and the endpoint follows the standard pattern).

Comment: Whoooooops, I must have skimmed over that, I'm getting tired. This works perfectly, thank you :)